# ObservableCollection CollectionChanged Event Not Being Raised

Tags: c#, observablecollection

In my class I've got an ObservableCollection and I'm listening to its CollectionChanged event.
Thing is when I do Fou.ButtonData = an ObservableCollection variable , CollectionChanged event is never called and CreateButtons() never happens.
How can I make this work?

Thanks

The code

```
class Fou
{
   private ObservableCollection<string> buttonData; 
    public ObservableCollection<string> ButtonData
    {
        get { return buttonData; }
        set { buttonData = value; }
    }

   public Fou()
   {
       buttonData = new ObservableCollection<string>();
        buttonData.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(buttonData_CollectionChanged);

   }

   void buttonData_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreateButtons();
    }
   }
```

Comment: What do you do to raise the event? Do you add or remove something from the collection? Please show the corresponding code.

Comment: what is CreateButtons() method doing?

Comment: CreateButtons() is never called so I don't think it matters

Comment: Fou.ButtonData = an ObservableCollection variable

Comment: The issue is, you're changing the property (INotifyPropertyChanged) but never changing the collection (which translates to changing the 'contents' of the collection, not changing the collection out)

Comment: I see now; I'll just call CreateButtons() in the Setter too.

Comment: The code "Fou.ButtonData = an ObservableCollection variable " is assigning a new reference value to the property. The original event handler assigned in the Fou constructor is now "stale" (listens to events on an unused object). Use JaredPar's answer and apply my comment and you'll be good-to-go, assuming that the "owner" of the collection isn't supposed to be class Fou...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the code sample it looks like the event is never raised because the `ObservableCollection<string>` is never actually changed.  It is created, it's event assigned to and never actually modified after that.  Is there some other code which modifies the collection.

Additionally there is a bug in the setter of `ButtonData`.  You are allowing another piece of code to change the `ObservableCollection<string>` but you are not listening to it's `CollectionChanged` event nor are you disconnecting from the previous one.  I would make this a readonly property or change it to the following

```
public ObservableCollection<string> ButtonData
{
  get { return buttonData; }
  set 
  { 
    if (buttonData != null) {
      buttonData.CollectionChanged -= buttonData_CollectionChanged;
    }
    buttonData = value;
    if (buttonData != null) {
      buttonData.CollectionChanged += buttonData_CollectionChanged;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so when you set an ObservableCollection to a new set of data that is not an CollectionChanged event? Seems like it would be to me.

Comment: @mike it does have a `CollectionChanged` event but it's on a different instance.  You need to change your class to listen to the new `ObservableCollection<string>`'s event

Comment: Your set should really do a null reference check prior to removing the event handler and prior to adding the event handler .

Comment: I'll add CreateButtons() to the Setter along with your code, thanks

Comment: the act of setting an ObservableCollection to a new instance of ObservableCollection *wouldn't* be a `CollectionChanged` event.  setting the collection itself would be a `PropertyChanged` event.  changing the **contents** of the ObservableCollection fires `CollectionChanged` events.